# Make QgsVectorLayer().getFeatures() ignore an existing filter

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, filter, pyqgis-3

When retrieving features from a layer with PyQGIS by sth. like

```
feat = [f for f in my_lyr.getFeatures('"road_name" = \'myroad\'')]
```

the resulting `feat` list is empty in cases where a filter is applied that does not cover `'my_road'`.

Is there a way or a recommended workaroud to make `getFeatures()` ignore an existing filter? Perhaps creating a memory layer with all features from the original layer and do the request on this memory layer?

Comment: What about disabling it with [QgsFeatureRequest::disableFilter()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#ad2c49b2da6b3384bd35aa58eb9eced62) and then re-setting it with [QgsFeatureRequest::setFilterExpression()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#aa7c168ddbcaaaa88eafb92340880e773)? You can return the existing filter by using [QgsFeatureRequest::filterExpression()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureRequest.html#a4b0a3038006e54733b242557520aef27)

Comment: `SetSubsetString` no funciona?